# Per-process network activity monitor

Tags: windows, networking

Is there an application for Windows XP/Vista/7 that displays per-process network traffic?

It would be better if they have visual graphs like [FreeMeter](http://sourceforge.net/projects/freemeter/).

Comment: Question is not complete because it doesn't mention the operating system and the only attached tag is irrelevant.

Comment: Oh right, edited the question.

Answer (score 5):

Windows 7 has a resource monitor built in that will show the network activity for each process as well as a host of other useful information.

Be warned looking at this is very addictive!

Answer (score 0):

On Windows you can try [NetLimiter](http://www.netlimiter.com/).

Comment: This is an ancient post, but please consider expanding the answer.  Just pointing to a product isn't considered an answer by current standards because it doesn't indicate anything about why it's a good solution or how to accomplish the solution.  Good guidance on recommending software [here](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers).  Thanks.

Comment: @fixer1234 if I don't get to it (and I won't soon) I'm happy for you (or anyone) to make an edit